# loss of parameters when using windows.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, parameters, reference, parameter-passing, settimeout

I want to show an ongoing number with JavaScript.

For this I have developed the following example:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert(i);
  },1000*i);
}
```

Unfortunately the number 100 is shown every time. I think it is because `i` is a reference?

How can this be changed in the parameter passing?

Comment: So you are actually clicking 100 alert boxes everytime you are testing your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JS does not wait and proceeds finishing the loop before the timeouts expire. By then, `i` is already 100.

To work around this issue, your timeout should have a local reference of `i`. That way, it's not referencing the `i` that is already 100 by then, but references `i` at that time of the loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
  (function(i){
    //shadowing the loop-i with the function-i
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      //thus, this callback is referencing the i from the function
      //and not the loop's i
      alert(i);
    },1000*i);
  }(i));
}
```